# Unable to configure IPv6 correctly in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6, ovh, netplan

I have a cloud instance on OVH which is accessible over IPv4 but not IPv6. It's running Ubuntu 18.04. I've found conflicting advice about using netplan vs configuring systemd-networkd directly, but all of the things I've tried don't seem to have any effect.

In OVH's web interface I have these addresses defined for me:

> IPv6: 2607:5300:201:2100::5d4
>
> Gateway: 2607:5300:201:2100::1

According to the guides I've read, I've configured netplan like this:

`/etc/netplan/90-ipv6.yml`

```
network:
    ethernets:
        ens3:
            match:
                macaddress: fa:16:3e:53:64:ce
            set-name: ens3
            addresses:
                - 2607:5300:201:2100::5d4/64
            gateway6: 2607:5300:201:2100::1
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                    - 2001:41d0:3:163::1

    version: 2
```

And systemd-networkd like this:

`/etc/systemd/network/10-ens3.network`

```
[Match]
Name=ens3

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
Gateway=2607:5300:201:2100::1
DNS=2001:41d0:3:163::1
Destination=2607:5300:201:2100::1

[Address]
Address=2607:5300:201:2100::5d4/64

[Route]
Destination=2607:5300:201:2100::1
Scope=link
```

My `ip addr` output looks like this:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:53:64:ce brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 54.39.191.97/32 scope global dynamic ens3
       valid_lft 85848sec preferred_lft 85848sec
    inet6 2607:5300:201:2100::5d4/0 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe53:64ce/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I can ping the gateway and get a response. However I cannot get a response from the server from any other location over IPv6, and a `ping6 google.com` from this server results in:

```
PING google.com(yul02s05-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4020:805::200e)) 56 data bytes
From [hostname] (2607:5300:201:2100::5d4) icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
...
--- google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4085ms
```

The only thing I haven't tried is rebooting the server, as it's live and I'd really rather not.

What am I missing? I don't really know what I'm doing, so it might be something very obvious.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Updated the prefix to /64. This configuration also doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure that prefix and gateway address are correct? Check in your control panel and confirm it.

Comment: The control panel doesn't have an explicit prefix, so I'm not sure, no. Gateway is definitely correct though.

Comment: Oh you're right, they don't give an explicit prefix. The correct prefix is /64.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I started with but it also didn't work. I've changed it back so it's correct but it doesn't fix the problem unfortunately.

Comment: Unsure if this is relevant, but I still get /0 in `inet6 2607:5300:201:2100::5d4/0 scope global` after changing the prefix and restarting networkd.

Comment: Hm, that gateway address isn't even reachable from outside. I suspect OVH might have screwed something up.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right about the /0 indicating you've got something wrong. What exactly, I'm not sure. I'd reboot the whole VPS at this point, and then check `dmesg` messages on the next boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually fixed this issue by changing something I didn't outline in my question, unfortunately.

In following a guide to setting up IPv6 with netplan, I had edited my netplan config to also include IPv4 address config in a separate, existing file `50-cloud-init.yaml`. Although the addresses matched the provided IPs for my instance, they must have conflicted with some other config elsewhere, and this was the root of my problem (where I believe seeing `/0` in the output of `ip addr` indeed indicated an issue).

Removing the IPv4 address and gateway values from my netplan config, so that the only thing I was setting were IPv6 address and gateway, and applying the new configuration, fixed the issue.

For anyone else who ends up getting into this situation, [this blog post](https://florianjensen.com/2019/11/02/enabling-ipv6-on-ovhs-public-cloud-with-netplan/) I found describes exactly what needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

The correct IPv6 prefix for OVHcloud VPS is /64, not /128 or /0.